# SP13 redirecting web pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

There are multiple ways to redirect website in SharePoint. Such as using content editor web part or changing the bookmark or http redirect.  However, I seeking the easiest steps on how redirect the page? Is it done in SP developer?  Thanks for you assistance.

Edited (7/28/14):  After a little more research, the following line of code placed into a script editor should allow the end-user to be redirected to the desired site.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://google">`

However, the site is not redirected right away. Do you know that can take away the pause in-between the page being redirected?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use JavaScript unless there is a specific reason not to:

```
<script>
location.replace("http://new.url.here/path/object.ext");
</script>
```

It is near-immediate and replaces the page in history, so you don't have a loop set up if someone uses the back button.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get instant redirect, you'd need to modify the timeout value, so the meta redirect would look like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://google">
```

That way of doing redirect has a side effect, you'd not be able to modify the original page through the standard SharePoint UI. If required to modify anything in future you should delete "Script editor" web part first.